# Cygnus install on localhost

Tags: connector, fiware, fiware-cygnus

By following this guide

```
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/blob/master/flume/doc/quick_start_guide.md
```

I tried to use

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

But I got this error

```
time=2015-03-11T17:35:01.965CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=warn | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
time=2015-03-11T17:35:01.965CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=warn | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed Server@57c59fac: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
time=2015-03-11T17:35:01.965CET | lvl=FATAL | trans= | function=run | comp=Cygnus | msg=es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.http.JettyServer[63] : Fatal error running the Management Interface. Details=Address already in use
```

And besides this error. I use service cygnus status  and start correctly.

```
    time=2015-03-11T17:46:52.337CET | lvl=ERROR | trans= | function=run | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable[253] : Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running HTTP Server found in source: http-source before I started one.Will not attempt to start.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.start(HTTPSource.java:137)
    at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

I change the port to 8085 8084 8083 ...  see that he read the conf and ignore this conf ...

```
[root@alex alex]# /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf -f /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console [-p 8085]
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.34.x86_64//bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf -n cygnusagent '[-p' '8085]'
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.882CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=start | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.895CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=run | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.906CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[101] : Configuration property ignored: CONFIG_FILE = /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.907CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[101] : Configuration property ignored: CONFIG_FOLDER = /usr/cygnus/conf
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.907CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[101] : Configuration property ignored: AGENT_NAME = cygnusagent
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.907CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[101] : Configuration property ignored: CYGNUS_USER = root
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.907CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[101] : Configuration property ignored: LOGFILE_NAME = cygnus.log
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.907CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[101] : Configuration property ignored: ADMIN_PORT = 8085
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.907CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=validateConfiguration | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[140] : Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: []
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.908CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=getConfiguration | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[138] : No configuration found for this host:cygnusagent
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.913CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=startAllComponents | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.925CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=startManagementInterface | comp=Cygnus | msg=es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[85] : Starting a Jetty server listening on port 8081 (Management Interface)
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.942CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.942CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=stopAllComponents | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[101] : Shutting down configuration: { sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.942CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : jetty-6.1.26
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.942CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=startAllComponents | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.949CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=startManagementInterface | comp=Cygnus | msg=es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[85] : Starting a Jetty server listening on port 8081 (Management Interface)
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.958CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : jetty-6.1.26
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.978CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=warn | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081: java.net.SocketException: Address already in use
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.980CET | lvl=INFO | trans= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.982CET | lvl=WARN | trans= | function=warn | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed Server@6e811049: java.net.SocketException: Address already in use
time=2015-03-11T19:47:50.982CET | lvl=FATAL | trans= | function=run | comp=Cygnus | msg=es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.http.JettyServer[63] : Fatal error running the Management Interface. Details=Address already in use
```

Comment: "*0.0.0.0:8081: java.net.BindException: Address already in use*" you've some service running on port 8081

Comment: but i try to change this port, i put
ADMIN_PORT=8085                                                                                 on cygnus_instance_1.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alejandro, this is a well-known bug for Cygnus 0.7.0. A new 0.7.1 version was uploaded at the beginig of this week to the FIWARE repo. Anyway, that supposedly FATAL error (it is an error, but not FATAL :)) does not affect the behaviour of Cygnus since it only affects the Management Interface (which currently has only one method that returns the version you are running). Thus, Cygnus should be working properly in the port you have configured for the `HTTPSource` at your `/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf` file:

```
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
```

Before installing the new version, I recommend you to remove the previous one. I mean, do not simply run `yum install cygnus` in order to update the existent installacion, but actively `yum remove cygnus` and then `yum install cygnus`. The reason is another bug regarding the RPM deployment that was fixed witin version 0.7.1 as well.

Comment: What it is currently running in 8081?

Comment: The Management Interface. Current latest release API is described here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/installation_and_administration_guide/management_interface.md